# How can I remove json element by sub json value?

Tags: php, json, filtering, uniqueidentifier, reindex

My json like this :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]
```

I have variable `$id`

if `$id = 2`, it will remove json that have `id = 2`

if `$id = 3`, it will remove json that have `id = 3`

For example, it will remove json that have `id = 2`

The json above to be like this :

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]
```

When deleted, its id will be sorted back

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Input:

```
$json='[{"id": 1, "name": "xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 2, "name": "9Tg1QLJGiHPC39KP20iOgy3cYQSXOllJTEBGPcF7.jpeg"}, 
{"id": 3, "name": "fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]';
$id=2;
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e9e92648cf78446c02234ae79f47b406e1b1ff6)):

```
$new_id=0;
$input=json_decode($json,true);
foreach($input as $i=>$a){
    if($a['id']==$id){
        unset($input[$i]);                  // remove the desired subarray
    }else{
        $input[$i]['id']=++$new_id;         // set correct id value (and increment $new_id)
    }
}

$input=json_encode(array_values($input));   // re-index first-level keys & json encode
var_export($input);
```

Output:

```
'[{"id":1,"name":"xkCT0QUAK7alZkYkbrLUfxoYyn9aXMh2kyCZeYFW.jpeg"},
  {"id":2,"name":"fWEfhpRkfy44lqC3Ro1etJKmOOkMXnLJLT4ncS6x.png"}]'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help

Comment: Okay. I had delete it